# How to select distinct values from XML document using XPATH?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

How can I select only distinct elements for the XML document using XPATH?I've tried to use the 'distinct-values' function but it didn't work for some reason..

The XML is similar to the following:

```
<catalog>

<product>
<size>12</size>
<price>1000</price>
<rating>1</rating>
</product>

<product>
<size>10</size>
<price>1000</price>
<rating>1</rating>
<year>2010</year>
</product>

</catalog>
```

So what I want to get is the list of distinct children of all the product elements.In the given example it would be - size,price,rating,year
My xpath was something like : distinct-values(catalog/product/*)

Comment: distinct-values function used for only one value for and inline content or attribute content.What do you mean by distinct children exactly?Is it different element names like size,price,rating,not the values ?

Comment: Sorry..yeah,exactly.I want to get the list of all the distinct children element names

Comment: You may not be grab distinct names by XPath !

Comment: Excellent Question (+1). See my answer for solutions in XPath 2.0, and XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**In XPath 2.0**:

```
distinct-values(/*/*/*/name(.))
```

**In XPath 1.0 this cannot be produced with a single XPath expression**.

**Using XSLT 1.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select=
   "/*/*/*[not(../following::*/*
                       [not(name() = name(current()))]
               )
           ]">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ' ')"/>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document, the wanted result is produced**:

```
size price rating year
```

**A more efficient XSLT 1.0 transformation, using keys**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kpchildByName"
  match="product/*" use="name()"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select=
   "/*/*/*
         [generate-id()
         =
          generate-id(key('kpchildByName', name())[1])
          ]">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ' ')"/>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need the distinct values of the element names - something like:

```
distinct-values($catalog/product/*/name(.))
```

Answer (score 4):

`distinct-values()` is available in XPath 2.0. Are you using that?

If `distinct-values()` is not available, the standard way of getting distinct values is to use `not(@result = preceding:: @result)` to get unique @result. It will give you the first occurrence only.

Comment: I'm not sure which XPATH version I've got:) How can I find out about that?

Comment: That would only work if the list is sorted on your result