# How can I use XPath to select distinct elements based on multiple child elements?

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to use XPath to select distinct elements based on multiple child elements.

I have some XML like this:

```
<Cars>
  <Car>
    <Make>SuperCar</Make>
    <Year>2009</Year>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <Make>SuperCar</Make>
    <Year>2010</Year>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <Make>AwesomeCar</Make>
    <Year>2010</Year>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <Make>SuperCar</Make>
    <Year>2009</Year>
  </Car>
</Cars>
```

And I need to use XPath (I'm limited to XPath 1.0) to select only distinct elements, where distinct is defined by both `Make` and `Year`.

In the example above this would mean returning all of the `Car` objects except the last one (as this is a duplicate of the first `Car`).

In a typical situation (i.e. where objects were identified by a single key field) I would use an XPath similar to this:

```
/*/Car[not(./Id/text()=following-sibling::Car/Id/text())]
```

However, I can't quite work out how to adapt this to correctly use multiple fields.

I considered something like this:

```
/*/Car[not(./Make/text()=following-sibling::Car/Make/text()
   and ./Model/text()=following-sibling::Car/Model/text())]
```

But that checks if the `Make` is used anywhere and if the `Model` is used anywhere, without ensuring that they are necessarily used on the same `Car`. For example it incorrectly excludes the first `Car` from the following sample XML:

```
<Cars>
  <Car>
    <Make>SuperCar</Make>
    <Year>2009</Year>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <Make>SuperCar</Make>
    <Year>2010</Year>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <Make>AwesomeCar</Make>
    <Year>2009</Year>
  </Car>
</Cars>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You might be able to do this with `<xsl:key...>` and the `key()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem this is impossible using XPath1.0:

[How to select distinct values from XML document using XPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871707/how-to-select-distinct-values-from-xml-document-using-xpath?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The following XPath query returns distinct cars, based on Make and Year (while using your XML example):

```
/*/Car[not(./Make/text()=preceding-sibling::Car/Make/text() and ./Year/text()=preceding-sibling::Car/Year/text())]
```

Checking for preceding siblings is more obvious, cause they're already 'indexed'. The query above gives the following output:

```
<Car>
    <Make>SuperCar</Make>
    <Year>2009</Year>
</Car>
<Car>
    <Make>SuperCar</Make>
    <Year>2010</Year>
</Car>
<Car>
    <Make>AwesomeCar</Make>
    <Year>2010</Year>
</Car>
```

Comment: Appreciate the attempt but unfortunately it won't work. If you add a `{ AwesomeCar, 2009 }` `Car` to the start, your query will invalidly exclude `{ AwesomeCar, 2010 }`. The reason is that the `preceding-sibling` clauses aren't (and I don't think can be) enforced to refer to the same sibling at the same time. This means the XPath is read as (Any sibling has the Make) OR (Any sibling has the Year) rather than the intended (Any sibling has the Make and Year). An example of this is at http://www.xpathtester.com/saved/8706004d-076d-420d-b523-f54b9f7fff78 (Click Test to see output).