# Jasper Reports use Xpath functions

Tags: xpath, jasper-reports

We are using Jasper Report's xml datasource. To create some output, we would need the XPath `distinct-values()` function, [as described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871707/how-to-select-distinct-values-from-xml-document-using-xpath). If I use it like described, Jasper Studio gives me an error:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : Source text : ((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDa‌​taSource("distinct-values(/connections/message/type)")

Does anyone know how to use XPath functions in Jasper Reports, jrxml files?

Comment: Well, your "as described" link _does_ say that `distinct-values()` only works in XPath 2.0. Would you be so kind and say what error you get? Most likely, Jasper Reports only supports XPath 1.0.

Comment: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
 Source text : ((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("distinct-values(/connections/message/type)")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`distinct-values()` is a function that is exclusive to XPath 2.0. Unfortunately, [Jasper Reports only support XPath 1.0](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/523605/xpath-20-supported) (ironically, the forum post is about exactly the same thing).

The short answer is: no, there is no XPath 1.0 function that eliminates duplicate values from a set of nodes.

There might be ways around this problem, if you can show more of your input XML document.

---

**EDIT**: For the record, here is the answer the OP got from the Jasper Reports Forum:

> Hi, I talked with JR Team in order to better clarify the topic. So currently the version supported is XPath version 1.0. This because JR relies on Xalan or Jaxen for XPath support. These thirdy-part libraries currently support version 1.0.
>
> Looking at the Jaxen FAQ it seems to be a "strict" decision they made, focusing only on compatibility support: http://jaxen.codehaus.org/faq.html
>
> Which version of XPath does jaxen support? Does jaxen support XPath 2?
>
> jaxen supports XPath 1.0. It does not support XPath 2.0. XPath 2.0 is a very different spec with many things to recommend it and a few things not to like as well. However XPath 2.0 is not compatible with XPath 1.0. It is far from a simple upgrade from XPath 1.0. It has a very different data model, that might well require significant revisions to jaxen's internal data structures, and possibly a very different API as well.
>
> The current release plan focuses exclusively on XPath 1.0 compatibility. Perhaps one day someone will make a branch or fork of jaxen that supports XPath 2. However, this would be a significant undertaking, and so far little interest in this has been shown.
>
> Therefore for the moment we will stay with version 1.0 of XPath

I disagree with the "a few things not to like" about XPath 2.0, but it is a clear answer, at least.

Comment: Asked at jaser-reports whether xpath2 is already supported. http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/849509/does-jasper-reports-support-xpath-20 to get the final answer from them

Comment: @EhmKah That's a good idea, even if I suspect nothing has changed since 2008. The change needed would be the integration of an Xpath 2.0 engine.

Comment: @Matthias: I would expected that that might has happened in 7 (!) years.

Comment: @EhmKah People have been exceptionally slow at adopting XPath 2.0, but I hope I'm wrong in this case ;).